# Скорость работы программы.Распознавание информации на картинке. Microsoft api

Tags: python, распознавание, microsoft-api

Есть код:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import requests
from IPython.display import HTML
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import patches
from io import BytesIO
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64
import json

face_cascade                = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cap                    = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
shape                  = False
ds_factor              = 0.5
font                   = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
fontScale              =  0.5
fontColor              = (60,125,255)
lineType               = 2
putTextIntoVideo       = None
pressed                = False
origin                 = None
age                    = None 
gender                 = None

for i in range(44):
    cap.read()

subscription_key = "ключик который я вам не скажу"
assert subscription_key

headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key }
params = {
    'returnFaceId': 'true',
    'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
    'returnFaceAttributes': 'age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise',
}

face_api_url = 'https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?%s'%params

while True:
    try:
        ret, img = cap.read()

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray = np.array(gray, dtype='uint8') 
        face = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        cv2.imwrite("D:\\face.jpg",img)
        data = open("D:\\face.jpg","rb").read()

        response = requests.post(face_api_url, params=params, headers=headers,data=data)
        faces = response.json()

        print(faces)

        for face in faces:
            print("putting text1")
            fr = face["faceRectangle"]
            fa = face["faceAttributes"]
            origin = (fr["left"], fr["top"])
            age = fa["age"]
            gender = fa["gender"].capitalize()
            #cv2.rectangle(origin, fr["width"]fr["height"])
            print(origin)
            cv2.putText(img,
                        "Gender:" + str(gender) + " Age:" + str(age), 
                        (origin[0],origin[1]), 
                        font, 
                        fontScale,
                        fontColor,
                        lineType)
            print("putting text2")

        cv2.imshow("Microsoft-api",img)


        ch = 0xFF & cv2.waitKey(1)
        if ch == 27:
            break

    except Exception:
        pass

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Почему** при нахождении лица на фотографии , войдя в цикл for , программа приостанавливается?

**Как** ускорить работу программы?

P.S. Я использовал Microsoft - api.

Comment: вы делали профайлинг? В каком месте тратиться больше всего времени?

Comment: for face in faces: начиная с этого и пока цикл for не закончиться . Не делал , а что это такое?

Comment: @MaxU Ещё раз протестировав программу понял , что тратиться больше всего времени не в цикле , а при подключении к api (respone , respone.json()).Как думаете , тормоза могут быть из-за медленного интернета который возможно долго подключается к Microsoft - Api?

Comment: честно говоря не знаю - никогда не тспользовал этот сервис...